# remove thumbnail text in amazing slider

Tags: slider

I want to remove thumbnail text in amazing slider, but the problem is it removes bottom text in slider, too. Is there any solution to keep bottom text as special effect in amazing slider and remove the thumbnail text

Answer (score 5):

If You Want To do it using jQuery then you can use following code:

```
//Copy and paste in to your js Code
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".amazingslider-bullet-text-0").remove();
    jQuery(".amazingslider-bullet-image-0 img").css("height","100%");
    jQuery(".amazingslider-bullet-image-0").css("height","100%");
});
```

https://amazingslider.com/examples/jquery-image-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

firstly,  find following text--

`this.options.watermarktext`  in the amazingslider.js

if you got it like

```
this.options.watermarktext = this.options.vermk;
```

and replace it with

```
this.options.watermarktext = "";
```

It have worked for me.